# Migrate Data From Apache Hadoop to Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I'm looking for a reasonable and proper strategies to migrate data from Apache Hadoop to Cloudera Hadoop.

Comment: Question is far too broad... Standup the new cluster on the side, then use distcp would get the **datanodes**, but do you have other services like Hive or HBase?? Do you need **all the data** migrated?

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I have Hive service as well. I'm trying to set up new cluster with cloudera Hadoop and I should migrate all data from existing  cluster to the new one. I need move all data to the new cluster. Thanks for time and concern.

Comment: Hive has an export and import feature. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport  If you backup the namenode, the Hive metastore, and volumes of the datanodes, then you would have most, if not all, of the data backed up. But it is easier to have two clusters running, then move data a few datanodes at a time.